# wordpress downloadable product without checkout

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

im beginner in coding and working on a wordpress downloadable product site.
the problem that im facing with it, is that i have 2 type of files. **free** and **paid**.
so i want to add button that add the paid files to cart and go for checkout. thats ok, but my problem is with free files. i don't want free files go to cart too. i want them just to download instantly if the user is signed up to the site and if not signed up, redirect them to sign up page.
thanks for you help.

i tried to add direct link for free files in product summery but the problem is that i cant ask them to sign in and download link will be open to every body.

Comment: Did you try anything and can you code or not?

Comment: i used a plugin that lock the content base on user that you choose. but i will be glad if you can help me solve it by code. i have a short knowledge of coding but not familiar with php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-control/ .
Then you can put your direct link inside the shortcodes [content_control]Logged in content[/content_control] inside the product summary. The download link wont be visible until the user signs up and login.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i did the same thing with another plugin. i accidently saw element pack plugin. that plugin has a content control too. many thanks for your help.